# AngularJS: Custom 'select' directive - wrong ng-model value in angular 1.2.6/7

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm trying to create simple directive, which could be used like this

```
<select custom-select="types.SOME_TYPE" ng-model="a.SELECT" />
```

my directive:

```
m.directive('customSelect', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      selectModel: '=ngModel',
      options: '=customSelect'
    },             
    template: '<div><select name="selectModel" id="selectModel"\
               required ng-model="selectModel" \
               ng-options="o.key as o.label for o in options">\
               <option style="display:none" value="">Wybierz...</option>\
             </select></div>',
    compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
      return function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {            
      };
    }
  };
});
```

it works fine in angular 1.1.6, but it doesn't work properly in angular 1.2.6/1.2.7 - strange value is set for variable defined in `ng-model` (`a.SELECT` in this example)

If types.SOME_TYPE is array:

```
[
    {
      "key":"KEY_1",
      "label":"Label 1"
    },
    {
      "key":"KEY_2",
      "label":"Label 2"
    }
]
```

then a.SELECT will have these values:

1. for angular 1.1.6 it will be "KEY_1" or "KEY_2" - that's cool
2. for angular 1.2.6/7
       it will be "? string:KEY_1 ?" or "? string:KEY_2 ?" - that's strange!

Under angular 1.2.6/7 it works fine only if I'm using directive like this:

```
<some-no-select-tag custom-select="types.SOME_TYPE" ng-model="a.SELECT" />
```

Here is a demo: <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/la4TEyh53BxZufYZH3FX?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in Plunker/Fiddle?

Comment: i've updated your demo

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look deep into it, but the issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with `ngOptions` (e.g. using `ng-repeat` has the same effect). The issue must have its root in how Angular handles `ngModel` of `<select>` elements (possibly because of the `replace: true`?), as changing `ng-model` to a custom attribute name (e.g. `my-model`) solves the problem:

```
/* In HTML: */
<select custom-select="types.SOME_TYPE" my-model="a.SELECT" />

/* In directive definition: */
...
scope: {
  selectModel: '=myModel',
  ...
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/ZeH6e/)**.